# Cocos2D : How to detect that I moved a sprite in a specific zone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

2 things I'd like to do with cocos2D :
1) set a random board based on 6 png files (like a 6 tiles boardgame)
2) be able to move a sprite/pawn with my finger and detect on which tile the sprite/pawn was moved and trigger a specific action depending upon which tile is under my sprite/pawn...

any code examples ??? 
cheers,

Tibi.

Answer (score 0):

one way you could do it would be to create an array of 6 x/y coordinates, one for each of the locations of the tiles. you could use these to move your pawns to and to test if they are in these locations, i.e.

```
if (pawn.position.x == sotoredLoc.x && pawn.position.y == sotoredLoc.y)
[pawn runAction];
```

type thing...

for the random part you might want to search for how to create an array of unique random numbers.